# Не работает автозагрузка на Delphi 7\ Исключение класса ERegistryException

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

Программа добавилась в автозагрузку и не удаляется программно.
В Uses записано Registry

При написании в type ругается

```
procedure ChangeReg(StrName: ShortString; delete: Boolean);
var reg: TRegistry;
begin
reg := nil;
   try
     reg := TRegistry.Create;
     reg.RootKey := hkey_local_machine;
     reg.LazyWrite := False;
     reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', False);
       if not delete then reg.WriteString('NxNotes', Application.ExeName)
       else reg.DeleteValue('NxNotes');
    reg.CloseKey;
    reg.Free;
   except
  if Assigned(reg) then reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.CheckBox2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if CheckBox2.Checked then ChangeReg('NxNotes', False)
  else ChangeReg('NxNotes', True);
end;
```

В проекте Delphi вызывает исключение класса ERegistryException.

Comment: Какой ужасный код. Бедные мои глаза. Как мне теперь это развидеть? Где вас учили так писать?

Answer (score 3):

Все дело в не внимательности:
Вместо `reg.RootKey := hkey_local_machine;`
Нужно написать `reg.RootKey :=  HKEY_CURRENT_USER;`
Оставлю вопрос для других пользователей.